# Preventing leading white space in input field pattern

Tags: html, regex, forms, validation, input

## Problem

I'm trying to prevent leading whitespace from being used in an input whether through spaces or tabs by using a pattern, but I'm having issues with this regular expression `^(?!\s)([a-zA-Z0-9 _.'"()!?&@]){1,}$`, which I think is because I might not be escaping properly because of the quotation marks?

Ultimately, I want to make sure the input takes at least one character, but none of those characters be leading white space at the beginning of the query.

#### Invalid inputs

_This is a query
__This is a query

#### Valid inputs

This is a good input

abc

123

a

## index.html

```
  <form action="{% url 'master_search' %}" method="GET">
    <i class="fa fa-search search-icon-drilldown" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input type="text" class="nav__search--agency form-control inline" name="q" value="" placeholder="Search by employee name" pattern="^(?!\s)([a-zA-Z0-9 _.'"()!?&@]){1,}$" required>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm. If you want to allow everything that starts with a letter or number,

```
pattern="^[a-zA-Z1-9].*"
```

should do the job

Answer (score 0):

You could also negate a range by doing 

`^[^\s]+.*$`

which will match a line with a starting character that is not white space.

Answer (score -1):

This is A pattern , which is uses to input type in html, but for name validation I have been analysise the pattern 
`pattern="^(?!\s)[a-zA-Z ]{1,}$"` and I used the title `(title="Request Format:Not valid numeric val & special character. Only Character")` for Requested pattern form in my input type html form where `type="name"`