# Regex pattern for preventing leading whitespace in HTML input

Tags: html, regex

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z1-9].*">
```

How can I restrict the following input element from having leading whitespace, ie, it should always start with a character except a whitespace.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40250729/3102993) suggested I use `pattern="^[a-zA-Z1-9].*"` but it doesn't seem to work.

EDIT:

It works only if I wrap it in a form tag and a submit button. Clicking the button triggers the error. But I want to be able to restrict users from entering whitespace on the input box itself.

Comment: You need to implementiert a simple client sie logic for that, so JavaScript.

Comment: do i need the pattern in addition to the client side logic?

Comment: Depends on how you implement you logic ...

Comment: Was this helpful to you?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this without a form-tag we can use a JavaScript live input filter like this:

```js
var noLeadingSpace = /^\w.*$/;

$("input")
  .data("oldValue", "")
  .bind("input propertychange", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var newValue = $this.val();

    if (!noLeadingSpace.test(newValue))
        return $this.val($this.data("oldValue"));

    return $this.data("oldValue", newValue);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work, but it will be validated if you try to send a form.

```js
function myValidator(v){
  var input = document.getElementById('uglyWay')
  
  if(input){
    input.value = input.value.replace(/ /g, '')
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
<input id="uglyWay" oninput='myValidator()' type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z1-9].*">
<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: please check the edited orignal post. I want to be able to restrict users from entering whitespace on the input box itself.

Answer (score 0):

The Following Regex mentioned in question Works without wrapping inside form tag

```css
input[type="text"]:valid{
background:green;
}
input[type="text"]:invalid{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^[a-zA-Z1-9].*">
```